# How to make a table by adding data from one column to make one row?

Tags: python

I have a csv file that I need to make into a table

[image: placeholder texter]

```
Electric Ireland, John Smyth, 2017, 05, 12, 11.58, credit
Energia, Missy May, 2016, 12, 22, 122.52, debit
Vodafone, John Smyth, 2016, 11, 17, 20.00, debit
```

How can I make a table with the first column being each year 2019 2018 etc and the second the total debited each year and the next column the total credited like this

[image: place-holder text]

```
Year     Total Credited    Total Debited
2016     €123.45           €678.90
2017     €543.21           €987.60
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  A pair of unadorned, off-site links do not comprise a question.

Comment: In which format do you get the data? Do you have to copy it from an image or is it already in the program? For writing to a csv file you should have a look at the [csv library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a dictionary to track totals by year.
If file tmp.tmp is the name of your file, then the following code would work (assuming format consistent with the example data you provided).

```
def get_data(file):
  data={}
  with open(file,'r') as f:
    for line in f.read().split('\n'):
      company,agent,year,month,day,value,trantype=line.replace(' ','').split(',')
      year=int(year)
      value=float(value)
      if year not in data.keys(): data.update({year:{trantype:value}})
      elif trantype not in data[year].keys(): data[year].update({trantype:value})
      else: data[year][trantype]+=value
  return data

file='tmp.tmp'

data=get_data(file)
fmt_head='{:<9s}{:<17s}{:<13s}'
fmt_row='{:<9d}{:<17.2f}{:<13.2f}'

print fmt_head.format('Year','Total Credited','Total Debited')
for year in sorted(data.keys()):
  print fmt_row.format(year,data[year]['credit'] if 'credit' in data[year].keys() else 0.,data[year]['debit'] if 'debit' in data[year].keys() else 0.)
```